# Replace the Cell Value throughout the Entire Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I am using  `FndRplce()` that code which replaces `fnd = "Ilya Malikzada"` with `rplc = "Arham"` throughout the entire workbook.

But how to create such a code which works like: When i change any name from the below attached picture that effect should apply on entire workbook.

**For example** `"Ilya Malikzada"` `A2` has this first name so when i write on cell `A2` `Arham` then wherever is `"Ilya Malikzada"` on entire workbook should replace with `Arham`.

[image]

your help will be much appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub FndRplce()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant
Dim ReplaceCount As Long

fnd = "Ilya Malikzada"
rplc = "Arham"

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

  ReplaceCount = ReplaceCount + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sht.Cells, "*" & fnd & "*")

  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    
Next sht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the name input to be a variable you can reference the cell specifically to do so. Just make it obvious so the user knows that's the input. I use Cell `A1`, but you can adjust this and the sheet name accordingly. This reference can be a excel-named reference as well as long as you keep it within it's quotes

The adjustment I made was to your `rplc` line like so

`ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("A1").Value`

```
Sub FndRplce()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant
Dim ReplaceCount As Long

fnd = "Ilya Malikzada"
rplc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("A1").Value

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

  ReplaceCount = ReplaceCount + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sht.Cells, "*" & fnd & "*")

  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    
Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not what i am looking for.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It gives the impression you want a cell where you can put the rplc value to overwrite the other values.

Comment: Sure, I want that if i change the `Tomasz Dania` cell `A21` to `Leopards` then wherever  `Tomasz Dania` is available on the whole workbook should be replaced with `Leopards`. same process for any cell that is available in the range `A2:37`

Comment: That seems to be what I have answered, it's just a matter of remapping the cell references to suit your specific sheet. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, are you saying that all values in A2:A37 should overwrite every instance of `Tomasz Dania`? How would that handle multiple inputs?

Comment: Yes it can handle multiple outputs, I managed to write the code here you can see. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67999705/find-and-replace-throughout-the-entire-workbook/68001360#68001360)

Comment: So you have your answer then?

Comment: Yes i completed it.