# Find and Replace throughout the Entire Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have using this function which finds and replace the string throughout the entire workbook.

But i do not know why error is appearing `"run time error: Object variable or with block variable not set"` on `rngCheck = Me.Range("A2:A37")`

I tried alot to find the problem but its not find you help will be appreciated.

```
Sub FndRplce(fnd As String, rplc As String)

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim boolStatus As Boolean

boolStatus = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Next sht
Application.ScreenUpdating = boolStatus

End Sub




Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngCheck As Range
Dim strOld As String
Dim strNew As String

rngCheck = Me.Range("A2:A37")

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Intersect(Target, rngCheck) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

strNew = Target.Value

Application.Undo
strOld = Target.Value

Call FndRplce(strOld, strNew)

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `rngCheck` is declared as a range and it must be set: `Set rngCheck = Me.Range("A2:A37")`. You couldn't use this code in the way you try it...

Comment: Then how it will work as i wanted it to work, Any efficient way that you might have.

Comment: I do not know what "as i wanted it to work" should mean... But in order to **simple** accept that range you must follow my piece of advice. Did you try `Set rngCheck = Me.Range("A2:A37")` instead of `ngCheck = Me.Range("A2:A37")`?

Comment: No, i mean you might have better idea how to find and replace.. [Link old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985345/replace-the-cell-value-throughout-the-entire-workbook/67989861#67989861) Yes i changed but it goes stuck i cannot change any sheet or cell

Comment: So, does the error still exist? If  not, how to help you doing something which only you know in terms of find **what** and replace with **what**, in which circumstances?

Comment: I have attached a sheet link where i have been trying to change the name from sheet1 cell and wanted to change that name on entire workbook [Sheet Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HrpG2c5yzPy8dDo9ewevmYoAeWUxzRLG/view?usp=sharing) Yes error still exist sheet does not move i cannot not edit cells

Comment: I do not want looking to a sheet without knowing what is to be done. Can't you explain **in words** what you try accomplishing? Should i deduce it looking to a sheet with a piece of code which does not work?

Comment: I am trying to explain. I want that i have same names on multiple sheets. So i want when i change the Sheet1 Any cell for example i change the Sheet1 cell A2 that is `Leopards` to `king` so wherever `Leopards` is available on whole workbook should be replace with `king`

Comment: Then, you have two mistakes in your Subs. I mentioned the first one, and the second one is to replace ' LookIn:=xlValues` from the `Repalace` function parameters. It does not exist for this function. It should look as... In fact, you will not understand the code in the comment. I will place an answer with both your Subs corrected in order to make them work.

Comment: Didn't you find some time to test the corrected codes I posted? If tested, didn't them do what you need?

Comment: I was on lunch now came again will test it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next pieces of code:

1.Copy this one in the Sheet1 code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngCheck As Range, strOld As String, strNew As String, lastR As Long

    'Now, it calculates the last existing value in column "A:A":
    'no need to adapt the code after adding records
    lastR = Me.Range("A" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngCheck = Me.Range("A2:A" & lastR)
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Intersect(Target, rngCheck) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    strNew = Target.Value

    Application.Undo:  strOld = Target.Value

    Call FndRplce(strOld, strNew)
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

2. Copy the next Sub in a standard module. But take care to delete your existing one having the same name...

```
Sub FndRplce(fnd As String, rplc As String)
    Dim sht As Worksheet, boolStatus As Boolean

    boolStatus = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = boolStatus
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: That was little tricky that you modified it with Master Mind. @FaneDuru Thank you very much. Its working awesome.

Comment: @Arham Glad I could (finally) help... But how do you add new names? Manually? I think the code can be adapted to take the last added name (on the first empty row) and add it to the rest of the sheets. Not extremely simple, but neither very complicated. If interested and place such a question, I will try helping. If I will see the question and I should be available. You maybe tag me here, if interested in this direction...

Comment: Yes You are right. How i missed that thing which is much necessary. I will upload a new question for sure within an half hour.

Comment: [Link to Quest...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004640/find-and-replace-functions-has-one-problem-that-it-fills-the-empty-cells-when-ne)  @FaneDuru added.