# Find and Replace fills empty cells when new value is added to the range

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using below code to find and replace the text throughout the entire workbook.

The current issue I have been facing is when I add new name to the range. It pasted that name into all empty cells. It should not happen. It should work as find and replace not to fill the empty cells with newly added name.

I hope to get some help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngCheck As Range, strOld As String, strNew As String, lastR As Long

    'Now, it calculates the last existing value in column "A:A":
    'no need to adapt the code after adding records
    lastR = Me.Range("A" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngCheck = Me.Range("A2:A" & lastR)
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Intersect(Target, rngCheck) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    strNew = Target.Value

    Application.Undo:  strOld = Target.Value

    Call FndRplce(strOld, strNew)
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

2nd

```
Sub FndRplce(fnd As String, rplc As String)
    Dim sht As Worksheet, boolStatus As Boolean

    boolStatus = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = boolStatus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should prevent the replacement of empty cells

```
' your code here …

strNew = Target.Value
Application.Undo
strOld = Target.Value

If Not strOld = vbNullString Then
    Call FndRplce(strOld, strNew)
Else
    Target.Value = strNew
End If

' your code here …
```

And I recommend to replace

```
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

with

```
If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

and put it as very first line of the event. `CountLarge` prevents an overflow error if `Target` is a big amount of cells that exceeds `Long`.

Comment: I removed these lines from the above code `strNew = Target.Value
    
    Application.Undo:  strOld = Target.Value
    Call FndRplce(strOld, strNew)` and added new to the code and replaces this as well `If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: No, the code in the first block should replace the line `Call FndRplce(strOld, strNew)` in your code. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much @Pᴇʜ. Its working now accordingly. I do not understand `put it as very first line of the event. CountLarge` this line But i added this line to first line of event

Comment: This `If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` should be the first line of code before `Dim rngCheck As Range`.